# ffmpeg - copy http stream to multicast udp stream

Tags: ffmpeg, http, udp, multicast, copy

i try to "copy" many tvheadend http streams to multicast udp streams

the result should contain all streams:
video, audio's and subtitels (especially epg)
...and at best without transcoding

my example source stream:

```
# ffprobe http://10.10.2.170:9981/stream/channelnumber/1001
ffprobe version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] no frame!
....
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x55a817a25e60] no frame!
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://10.10.2.170:9981/stream/channelnumber/1001':
  Duration: N/A, start: 19831.703344, bitrate: N/A
  Program 10301
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Das Erste HD
      service_provider: ARD
    Stream #0:0[0x13ed]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x13ee](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x13ef](mis): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x13f0](deu): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x13f1](deu): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006) (hearing impaired)
    Stream #0:5[0x13f2](deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
```

my command:

```
# ffmpeg -re -i http://10.10.2.170:9981/stream/channelnumber/1001 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f mpegts udp://239.239.239.1:1234
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] no frame!
...
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x5628ad1df6e0] no frame!
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://10.10.2.170:9981/stream/channelnumber/1001':
  Duration: N/A, start: 19980.503344, bitrate: N/A
  Program 10301
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Das Erste HD
      service_provider: ARD
    Stream #0:0[0x13ed]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x13ee](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x13ef](mis): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x13f0](deu): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:4[0x13f1](deu): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006) (hearing impaired)
    Stream #0:5[0x13f2](deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 448 kb/s
Output #0, mpegts, to 'udp://239.239.239.1:1234':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1(deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpegts @ 0x5628ad1d08e0] PES packet size mismatch:00:08.59 bitrate=7046.5kbits/s speed=   1x
key    function= 49 q=-1.0 size=  101907kB time=00:01:55.39 bitrate=7234.6kbits/s speed=   1x
```

...and my unusable result:

ffprobe from udp stream:

```
# ffprobe udp://@239.239.239.1:1234
ffprobe version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] SPS unavailable in decode_picture_timing
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x556ead7845a0] no frame!
...
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@239.239.239.1:1234':
  Duration: N/A, start: 17.264000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 100 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 256 kb/s
```

is one of you having a tip or can help?

many thanks!

Comment: You need `-map 0` to map everything from the input to the output stream. Also, `-c copy` to simply copy all audio/video/subtitle streams, no need for individual `-vcodec` options. Update your ffmpeg to a newer version if possible.